# whether changing a 2010 Nissan Santra car Battery can cause the BCM to stop car from running

Tags: nissan, sentra, bcm

I have a 2010 Nissan Sentra that I am financing from Nissan. I got it from them after december 7, 2015. The car right now is not starting and it is back with Nissan servicing. They said that the problem is the BCM and something else, basically, there is a fuse blown. When the car was running, a week before towing it to Nissan, the car wouldn't start due to the old battery. We had to jump start it, so I had to keep it running and drive quick to Autozone to change the battery. After Autozone had changed the battery, right then, the light on the dashboard wouldn't come on. The light for the radio came on only if the headlight was turned on, but if off, the light will go off on the radio. The signal light won't come on etc.. but the car ran such that I was able to drive it back from Autozone to home, and to work and back the next day. The Saturday of that weekend, after reaching home from work and driving to Paterson to home, the car suddenly wouldn't start. Now Nissan said that the changing of the battery caused a fuse to be blown and it is AutoZone that cause the problem; AutoZone are stating that them changing the battery can not cause the car or BCM etc, to not make the car work. Please can someone tell me if Nissan is right.

Comment: Blowing fuses while hooking up a battery can happen, assuming it wasn't installed positive to negative etc... It's not very common though. Fuses can also blow while jump starting a car as well. I find it hard to believe that the IPDM fried if the battery and jump start were performed correctly. You should probably get a second opinion or provide specifics on what the dealer found wrong.

Comment: I know this post is old but since it was bumped I'll add a comment. A very common failure to the bcm of Nissan's are from low battery/no battery causing corruption damage to the eeprom containing immobilizer data.  No blown fuses in this case, but you would have a NO START. Sometimes you can repair/program immo with obd2 tool sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, a fuse was blown while jumping the battery if connections were made improperly. Less likely, if the battery was connected improperly or if a short occurred by contacting metal tools with the battery terminals cold have blown a fuse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the bcm can be damaged from battery problems. Its very common on Nissan cars.
What happens is the memory inside the bcm that stores the immobilizer data gets corrupted. Sometimes you can simply reprogram the keys and correct the problem but in some cases there is too much data corruption in the memory and all the bcm's values and ids are wiped out. In these cases you must replace the bcm or replace eeprom memory in it with good data.